# Uninstall/ disable php 5.6.9 osx Yosemite

Tags: macos, mac, homebrew, apache, php

I´m running osx yosemite with homebrew, apache, php5.6.9 and have installed php 5.3.
I need php 5.3 to run a certain api which known to have complications with ph5.6.9.
But how can I disable php 5.6.9 to use the 5.3?

Answer (score 1):

To switch versions:

```
brew unlink php56 && brew link php53
```

There are complete instructions for managing and using a specific version of PHP at the Github repo for homebrew-php:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php

Setup the homebrew/dupes tap which has dependencies we need:

```
$ brew tap homebrew/dupes
```

Setup the homebrew/versions tap which has dependencies we need:

```
$ brew tap homebrew/versions
```

Then, run the following in your command-line:

```
$ brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
```

**Usage**

Note: For a list of available configuration options run:

```
$ brew options php53
```

Once the tap is installed, you can install php53, php54, php55, php56, or any formulae you might need via:

```
$ brew install php53
```

…